# How to order the subjects in PlantUML sequence diagram?

Tags: uml, plantuml

I have a PlantUML sequence diagram where `Alice` exchanges messages with `Cecil` once and then only the communication with `Bob` happens. This flow causes the subjects are ordered by the time of their first interaction.

```
@startuml
Alice -> Cecil: hi
Cecil -> Alice: fu

Alice -> Bob: hi
Bob -> Alice : hello

Alice -> Bob: howdy?
Bob -> Alice: fine

Alice -> Bob: r u sure?
Bob -> Alice: ye
@enduml
```

[image]

It looks ugly - I want to avoid showing the interaction between `Alice` and `Bob` *over* `Cecil`.

How to assure a custom order of the subjects, i.e. `Alice` - `Bob` - `Cecil`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have found it out. Just use the keyword, `participant`. The order of generated participants follows the order of their definitions. Alternatively, it is possible to define the order explicitly (`participant Alice order 1`).

Source: [UML Sequence Diagram: Participants](https://plantuml-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/diagrams/sequence.html#participants)

```
@startuml
participant Alice
participant Bob
participant Cecil

Alice -> Cecil: hi
Cecil -> Alice: fu
Alice -> Bob: hi
Bob -> Alice : hello
Alice -> Bob: howdy?
Bob -> Alice: fine
Alice -> Bob: r u sure?
Bob -> Alice: ye
@enduml
```

[image]